# How to add new column in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I imported stock market data using pandas. Now, I want create a new column by creating a new variable like this:

```
New column = if close > close.shift(5):
Print (1)
Elif close < close.shift(5) :
Print (-1)
Else:
Print(0)
```

Is there a method to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Do provide a [mcve] of your data and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you try any code that did not work?

Answer (score 2):

Let us using `np.sign`

```
np.sign(colse-colse.shift(5))
```